# Deployment of Ditto and MongoDB using kubectl fails because of unsupported version "extensions/v1beta1"

Tags: kubectl, minikube, eclipse-ditto

I try to start Ditto using kubernetes/minikube by following the instructions in the projects README.txt. While deploying mongoDB and later the Ditto services with the command

```
kubectl apply -f deployment/kubernetes/mongodb/mongodb.yaml
```

I get the following error message:

```
error: unable to recognize "deployment/kubernetes/mongodb/mongodb.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

I think I have to change the version to "api/v1", but doing this causes the next error:

```
error: error validating "deployment/kubernetes/mongodb/mongodb.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I use the following versions:

Ditto: release-1.5

minikube version: v1.14.1

kubectl client version: Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2

kubectl server version: Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2"

Does anybody knwo how I can fix this problem. I don't know which fields and which values I have to add to make the .yaml files working as expected.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You should change the `apiVersion` in deployment definition to `apps/v1`, not `api/v1`. It should work without any errors. And `extensions/v1beta1` doesn't work because it was [deprecated and is no longer served in k8s v1.16](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the files in this PR here: https://github.com/eclipse/ditto/tree/master/deployment/kubernetes/deploymentFiles

The deployment files are updated and now use apiVersion: apps/v1.

Comment: please no "link only" answers. share your ideas here.

Comment: Please edit your answer as the link you provided is not valid any more.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a Community Wiki answer so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

> I get the following error message:
>
> ```
> error: unable to recognize "deployment/kubernetes/mongodb/mongodb.yaml": no matches for kind
> ```
>
> "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
>
> I think I have to change the version to "api/v1", but doing this
> causes the next error ...

You should change the  `apiVersion`  in `Deployment` definition to  `apps/v1`, not  `api/v1`. It should work without any errors. And  `extensions/v1beta1`  doesn't work because it was  [deprecated and is no longer served in k8s v1.16](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/).