# After starting Ditto services, pods toggle from "OK" to "Liveness probe failed" or "Readiness probe failed"

Tags: minikube, eclipse-ditto

I managed to get Ditto up and running on minikube, following the instructions provided in the README.txt file. I had to do some minor adjustments to the .yaml files (see [Deployment of Ditto and MongoDB using kubectl fails because of unsupported version "extensions/v1beta1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118807/deployment-of-ditto-and-mongodb-using-kubectl-fails-because-of-unsupported-versi)).

Now that the Ditto services have been started, the pods toggle from status "OK" to the following errors:

```
pod connectivity: Liveness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.6:8558/alive": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

pod gateway: Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.9:8558/ready": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

pod things: Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.5:8558/ready": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Back-off restarting failed container

pod things-search: Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.8:8558/ready": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Back-off restarting failed container

pod policies: Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.7:8558/ready": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Back-off restarting failed container

pod concierge: Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.4:8558/ready": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Even when all pods have the status "OK", I can't send POST requests without getting Error 502 (Bad Gateway).

Any help for solving this problem is highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is caused by a resource issue for your Minikube VM.
How many CPUs and Memory does the VM have?
Maybe you can you scale up resources and try again?

Comment: Thank you, it indeed was not sufficient memory resources

Answer (score 1):

I had several Problems with Ditto running in docker till I changed the CPU usage in docker from 4 to 8.

[Docker Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofe4p.png)

Since I am using a 4Core/8Thread I wonder if a setting of 4 does lead to the usage of 2 cores (on an old mac). Which seems to be too few for Ditto.

Thomas